# RTC Data Connection "closing" after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, webrtc

After a few seconds' worth of successful data transfers, my rtc data connection experiences a "closing" `readyState`:

[image]

My connection code is below:

```
    rtcConnection.sendChannel = rtcConnection.createDataChannel("sendChannel");
    rtcConnection.ondatachannel = receiveChannelCallback;


    function receiveChannelCallback(initEvent) {
       initEvent.channel.onmessage = function (dataEvent) {
          dataEventHandler.handleInboundEvent({
             dataEventType: enums.dataEvents.transmitMedia,
             mediaData: dataEvent.data
          })
       };
    }
```

Sending (screenshot code):

```
            remoteConnection.sendChannel.send(metadata);
            remoteConnection.sendChannel.send(mediaBuffer);
```

What would cause a data connection state to move into `closing` - and what is the proper way to recover this connection and re-open it?

In case it matters - P2P streaming between these two `RTCPeerConnections` maintains functionality - it's just the data connection that closes.

Comment: There used to be a bug around this, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405545
Try saving a reference to the datachannel

Comment: @PhilippHancke I save the datachannel reference via `rtcConnection.sendChannel` - or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: you're only saving the data channel you create -- not the one you are receiving in ondatachannel. Now that bug should not exist anymore but...

Comment: @PhilippHancke would something like `rtcConnection.receiveChannel = initEvent.channel` at line 1 of `receiveChannelCallback` do what you're recommending?

Comment: yes, that should work.

Comment: 5 years later and its not fixed at all. you have to save a reference still